# Build a stack trace up using node.js and native promises

Tags: node.js, express, stack-trace, es6-promise

We have an express API application in which we utilize ES6's native promises.

Our current setup for a simple get would be

```
//controller.js snippet
get: function (req, res, next) {
       repository.getObject()
        .then(function (response) {
            return res.status(200).json(response);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return next(err);
        });
}

//repository.js snippet
getObject:function(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var sql = SELECT * FROM table;
        db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            return resolve(result.rows));
        });
    }); 
}

//app.js snippet
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
   logger.log(err, err.stack)
});
```

The problem we are seeing is that the err.stack that gets logged only includes the trace from the db node module. I would like tthe trace to include the fact  that controller.js called repository.js.

Rather than reject(err) I know I can do reject(new Error(err)) but I'm not sure if that is a good practice to have all over our application

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

> Calls to **next()** and **next(err)** indicate that the current handler is
>   complete and in what state. **next(err)** will **skip** all remaining handlers
>   in the chain **except** for those that are set up to handle errors.

So your `controller.js` needs to be like this-

```
//controller.js snippet
get: function (err, req, res, next) {
   repository.getObject()
    .then(function (response) {
        return res.status(200).json(response);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        return next(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: The crux of the problem is that we have functions that return promises calling other functions returning promises. If the last function to return a promise errors, it will reject and "bubble" up our promise chain. The stack trace associated with that error will only reference the function that errored and not how it go there. I'm not sure how the solution above will work with a deeper promise chain. Is it bad practice to have these promises nested as we do?

Comment: It is perfectly valid to have functions returning promises and calling another function which return promise. With promises chained together either you can provide error handler in each `then` chain and throw error again from there or you can just have one error handler at the end of promise chain.